# Description of variables for a credit scoring model

Tags: economic-terms, credit

I'm working with a credit scoring model. I have a dataset that includes 42 variables.
I don't know what are mean 6 variables:

1. remaining_mat
2. live_status
3. repaid_status
4. months_since_2mia
5. avg_mia_6m
6. max_mia_6m

**Question.** I am lookig for variable's description. What are mean 6 variables above?

Is it possible that *remaining_mat* is *Remaining Minimum Alternate Tax*?

Is it possible that *months_since_2mia* is *months since 2 months in arrears*?

Comment: Welcome to economics.se. As you can learn from our help center opinion based questions are off topic on this site. Every model/dataset will have its own naming conventions and there is no way how can anyone answer this question without opinion without knowing precisely from which paper you took the model. If the model was developed in house at some firm then you need to ask your colleagues or search for manual to the model or metadata

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what sort of credit product is this on (mortgage, credit card, personal loan)? Different products may use different terminology.

My first guess, would be that "mat" means maturity, live means whether the loan has been closed (i.e. current, delinquent, charge off).

MIA is not the terminology I'm familiar with, but "months in arrears" sounds plausible since they are typically tracked by month and from the date of first missed payment. However, I think the standard is 120 days past due (until charge off), so 6 months may be indicative of a longer loan or set of loans (mortgages?).